# Loss of session variables after exporting my selenium code (undetected_chromedriver) with pyinstaller

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller, undetected-chromedriver

To explain my program, I create an account on a site with a chrome profile then I close the driver. Then I reopen the created profile to connect to the automatic account with the session variables.
Here is my configuration for my driver

```
def setup_chrome_driver():
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    profile = date.strftime("%H%M%S")
    userDataDir = resource_path(f".\\profiles\\profile{profile}")
    options.user_data_dir = userDataDir
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    #options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options,version_main=109)
    return driver,profile
```

then I reopen the profile with this

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
userDataDir = resource_path(f".\\profiles\\profile{profile}")
options.user_data_dir = userDataDir
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

My resource_path fonction is

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

The account is created with the .exe program but When I reopen the profile (the right one), I see the browsing history. However the connection to the account is no longer active

Here is the command to convert .py into .exe
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --add-data "C:/profiles;." --add-data  "C:/ue_installer.py"

Do you know why I am losing the connection?